# How to Popup Alert() from asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to create a Popup for an ASP:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged event in the aspx code / javascript (not codebehind).

I have a ddl list of marriage status ("Single", "Divorced", etc...).  When an item in the list is selected I need a popup box / message box / Alert to show a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that, You don't need `Jquery` and `Jquery.UI` at all ( :-/ ).

To be honest, this simple things can be done with pure `javascript`.

```
function showme(selEle) {
  alert('Selected value : '+selEle.value.toString()+'\nSelected item : '+selEle.options[selEle.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}


<asp:DropDownList ID="Status" runat="server" Enabled="true" onchange="showme(this)">
<asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Of course, You can use `div` like popup box.

There is simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6yLw0tw/) example. You can play with popup box how You want.

Comment: Not sure, but I think he is looking for a way to directly using it with WebForms...updating your answer with relevant aspx code might be helpful

Comment: Should that be `onchange="showme(this);"`? That way you pass in the element and the showme function can then grab the value from the changed control?

Comment: Thank you.  It seems my problem was from using OnSelectedIndexChanged.  That gave me all sorts of errors.   I've started a new question to learn why the 'onchange' event doesn't appear in Intellisense.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789899/why-does-ddl-onchange-event-not-appear-in-intellisense

Comment: To keep it short I used:  onchange = "alert('MyMessageHere');